# Styling UserControls

Tags: wpf, user-controls, styles, custom-controls

The UserControl below works well but I would like to make it easier to change the Style.

One thing I have tried is to move the Style into a generic button style in the ResourceDictionary, but that gets an error as shown below.

The other thing I tried is to convert this to a Custom Control, but that is the subject of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351682/converting-a-usercontrol-to-a-custome-control)

There are several similar buttons currently defined as UserControls. Is there a recommended way to change the Style of all of them?

Cheers

## Failed attempt to apply a style using another style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource blueButtonStyle}"/>
</Style>

Error: Style object is not allowed to affect the style property of the object to which it applies
```

## UserControl XAML

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Smack.Core.Presentation.Wpf;component/Themes/generic.xaml" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<Button x:Name="_button" Style="{StaticResource blueButtonStyle}" Command="{Binding AddNewItemCommand}"  >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Image Source="{resx:Resx ResxName=Smack.Core.Presentation.Resources.MasterDetail, Key=bullet_add}" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <AccessText x:Name="_accesText" VerticalAlignment="Center">_Add New Subject</AccessText>
        <ContentPresenter/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

## UserControl Code Behind

```
public partial class AddNewItemButton : UserControl
{
    public AddNewItemButton() { InitializeComponent(); }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SubjectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Subject", typeof (string), typeof (AddNewItemButton),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnSubjectChanged));

    public string Subject { get { return (string) GetValue(SubjectProperty); } set { SetValue(SubjectProperty, value); } }

    private static void OnSubjectChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) {
        var control = obj as AddNewItemButton;
        if (control == null) return;

        control._accesText.Text = "_" + string.Format(MasterDetail.Subject_AddNew_Label, control.Subject.Capitalize());

        control._button.ToolTip = string.Format(MasterDetail.Subject_AddNew_ToolTip, control.Subject.ToLower());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may have better luck using your first approach:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource blueButtonStyle}"/>
</Style>
```

It's understandable that you'd get an error by setting a style from within a style.  Instead, you can use the "BasedOn" attribute to force your "default" style to inherit from your desired style;

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource blueButtonStyle}">
    <!-- Nothing Here --> 
</Style>
```

That should do what you want; that is, if I understand your question correctly (it seems a bit unclear, to be honest).

As a side note, there's not really any reason to use a custom user control for this button.  That can all be done with a regular button, using the core tools of WPF like Bindings and Converters to display dynamically-changing text in the button content and tooltip.

Comment: Yeah, I should have caught that, and it works. Will award the answer as soon as SO lets me (~2 minutes to go!). Cheers

Comment: @BTownKid. I want to use the button in several presentations, and it feels more encapsulated this way. Are you suggesting to put the bindings into a Style?

Comment: That seems best, to me.  In my opinion, creating new user controls is only needed for brand new functionality; this appears to just be doing the job of the bindings, which - as you said - can be reused in a style instead.

Comment: @BTownKD. I did that originally but I didn't know where to put the SubjectProperty, now a DP in the UserControl. It comes from a resx, as opposed to a view model bound property. Where would you put that in a Style?

Comment: You could - for instance - set the text in the style, and use DataTriggers bound to a "Subject" ViewModel property; when the specific Subject trigger is hit, the new text is set.

Or even simpler; bind the button text directly to a ViewModel string property, which is based on the current Subject.